# In C++ is it possible to override virtual methods upon initialization?

Tags: c++, oop, initialization

When I wrote java it was possible to override abstract method when you initialized a class. I think it looked something like this:

```
AbstractClass object = new AbstractClass(){
   void inheritedMethod(){
      ...
   }
};
```

Is this possible to do in C++, and if so what is the syntax?

Comment: Outside of templates and nefarious schemes that use intializer lists, lambdas, and fancy constructor syntax, C++ class declarations are pretty straight forward and hasn't changed much in years. We still like to put our declarations in a "header" and source in a cpp file (to avoid having our source be included everywhere).

Comment: Very often, function pointers are used to get the effect you seem to be after here.

Comment: Removing `[java]` as the answer won't have anything to do with Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok, I never tagged [java] though, maybe it happened automatically, due to the mention in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible, C++ doesn't allow that.

You first have to define a new, separate class that inherits from `AbstractClass` and instantiate that class.

Comment: Java also requires you to define a new, separate class that inherits from AbstractClass and instantiate that class -- it's just an anonymous class. There's a fairly close analogue for C++ -- see my answer.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer: you're right to mention local class definitions, I had that in mind too but didn't think about mentioning it (I guess I thought it was too obvious or something).

Answer (score 5):

When you do this in Java, you're creating a concrete class, locally defined without a name.

You can come close to this in C++ with a local class definition followed by a variable declaration.

```
    class Concrete : public AbstractClass {
        public:
        void inheritedMethod() {
            cout<<"inherited method";
        }
    } object;
```

For example, in context:

```
class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual void inheritedMethod() =0;
};

void bar() {
    class Concrete : public AbstractClass {
        public:
        void inheritedMethod() {
            cout<<"inherited method";
        }
    } object;

    object.inheritedMethod();
};
```

Comment: This actually scales much better than the lambda constructor trick. But the lambda constructor gets lambda benefits.

Comment: This seems a closer analogue. And it supports overriding multiple methods.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not. You have to derive a child class and implement the pure virtual method, then make an object.

However you can simulate something by lambda functions:

```
class AbstractClass
{
public:
    AbstractClass(std::function<void()> func_) : func(std::move(func_)) {}

    const std::function<void()> func;
};

int main()
{
    AbstractClass object([]()
    {
        // the code
    });

    object.func();
}
```

Comment: Interesting workaround. Of course this is not nearly as flexible as Java's syntax but that's probably the best we can get in C++. +1

Comment: @syam: Absolutely you're right. we can have this in our mind to achieve some goals.

Comment: By the way, this is not related to OP's question but your constructor is a perfect candidate for C++11's pass-by-value/move optimization (another thing which is hard to get used to ^_^).

Comment: @syam: C++98 habits die hard :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all,we cannot declare an object from an abstract class, so it is not possible.

Comment: Actually, whether `AbstractClass` is indeed abstract or not is irrelevant. It's still impossible even if one wanted to override a virtual method from a concrete class.